# How to kill a Greensock Draggable instance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I am using greensock's Draggable library. Everything is working fine, except I can not get the "kill" method to work. This method is recommended to clear the Draggable instance from memory when you don't use it anymore.

[Docs: http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Utils/Draggable/kill/](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Utils/Draggable/kill/)

Not working:

```
var dr = new Draggable(..);
dr.kill();
```

Also not working:

```
Draggable.create(".tile", ....);
Draggable.kill(".tile");
```

Also not working:

```
var jq = jQuery("#box");
Draggable.create(jq, ...);
Draggable.kill(jq);
// nope...
jq.kill();
```

Tracing out the method results in undefined, even while the code IS in the library!

```
console.log("kill method is " + Draggable.kill);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me (using Draggable 0.10.3):

```
// Create
Draggable.create("#test", {});

// Kill
Draggable.get("#test").kill();
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed the 'get' function. Also it seems that var dr = new Draggable() returns an array. So you can also kill() each entry in the array: dr[0].kill();